# Error while trying to process a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unicode, encode

I have a list of dictionaries (key with both single and multiple values) in Python.

Apparently, the data is in unicode format which is the issue i m facing.

```
x = "..." my list of dictionaries  #printing type(x) gave me "unicode"
```

I want to be able to do

```
for i in x:
    print i[key]
```

This does not seem straight forward with the unicode i guess. So i did,

```
r = x.encode('utf8') # printing type(r) gave me "str"
```

but when i do

```
 for i in r: #r here is in str format
        print i[key]
```

I get the following error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"

It is very confusing!

Comment: If your list of dictionaries is a string, then `i` would be a single character and hence you won't be able to do a `i[key]`

Comment: So how do i fix it?. I was able to do it as "str" on python CLI on MAc though. That's the strangest part. I copied 'x' onto MAC and the type(x) appears to be string. and I could iterate through it like i wanted - got the right values too. On centOS i have this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list of dictionaries is a string as you mentioned in the question, then use `ast` modules' `literal_eval()` to convert it into a list of dictionaries. Then you can access the keys and values in the dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> data = "[{'a':'b'}, {'a':'d'}, {'a':'f'}]"

>>> type(data)
<type 'str'>

>>> list_of_dicts = ast.literal_eval(data)
>>> type(list_of_dicts)
<type 'list'>

>>> key = 'a'
>>> for i in list_of_dicts:
...     print i[key]
...
b
d
f
```